# Allocate an amount in one cell amongst or between several cells based on the value of each of the several cells

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

Here is the link that relates to my question:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1dnWuREv3Rf2EWyDQDnyHyZWZ8ItbyKt_EfxPQwWhTnA/edit?usp=sharing

Cell C13 is a Retirement Annuity contribution of my choosing.

Column E is taxable income at various marginal tax rates.

I can reduce my taxable income by the value in Cell C13.

Currently I am manually allocating the value in Cell C13 into Column H.

In this example I have manually inserted $88999 into H21 and then calculated H20.
I would like this somehow to be dynamic.

The allocated $89999 to H21 because I need to max out the amount in E21 before allocating to the next cell.

Changing Gross Income in Cell C8 dynamically populates Column E so this makes my problem all the more challenging.

In a nutshell, the only cells that should be editable are yellow. I would like Column H NOT to be yellow.

Comment: Hi Tedinoz, thanks for your guidance. I hope this is he correct place to post my follow up question:) Can you perhaps take a look at my revisions to show me where I'm going wrong. Here's the link: – https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1dnWuREv3Rf2EWyDQDnyHyZWZ8ItbyKt_EfxPQwWhTnA/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

You want a formula to calculate the tax payable on any given value of taxable income.

Try this formula In Cell C11 (and then copy to Cell C14):

`=VLOOKUP(C11,$A$19:$D$25,4,TRUE)+round((C11-(VLOOKUP(C11,$A$19:$D$25,1,1)-1))*(VLOOKUP(C11,$A$19:$E$25,5,TRUE)),0)`

The elements of the formula are:

- `VLOOKUP(C11,$A$19:$D$25,4,TRUE)` - base tax for the applicable threshold
- `(C11-(VLOOKUP(C11,$A$19:$D$25,1,1)-1))` - the taxable income that applies to the final threshold
- `VLOOKUP(C11,$A$19:$E$25,5,TRUE)` - the marginal tax rate that applies to this threshold.

---

**Changes required**

To do this, you need to structure the tax rates along the following lines.

**Tax Rates**

[image: taxrates]

The key to this table is that the calculation of the "Base Tax" for the previous threshold, and the marginal tax rate for each threshold.

---

**Tax Calculations**

[image: taxable income]